# What’s the deal with code red in 28 weeks Later?

Tags: plot-explanation, 28-days-later

In *28 weeks* later, the military initiates **Code Red** when the virus breaks out, and the soldiers were order to kill everyone, even those who were healthy.

What’s the point of it though?

It made for an impressive shootout for sure, but it isn’t very effective. The infected turn into zombies pretty much instantly, so it’s not possible for the infected to hide their infection.

Was it somehow explained in the movie, or is just a plot convenience to give us a cool scene?

Comment: I think the idea was the infection was spreading so quickly they decided to try and contain the situation by indiscriminately killing everyone. Trying to pick out only the infected was not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alice who is found earlier in the movie was shown to be an asymptomatic carrier of the rage virus. After kissing Don he gets infected and kills her.

so the logic behind it is that somebody can get the virus without getting all the symptoms (this being turned in to one of the monsters). So letting seemingly uninfected people pass has the risk of them being such carriers and infect others.

Comment: Yes, but the shooting happens a short time later they discover Alice. But it is implied that code red was planned to be this way for a long time. It isn’t very consistent

Comment: @Aditya In such a world it would not surprise me that such tactics are immediately altered or added to the set of commands. There isn't any hard form of government on sight that enforces a bureaucratic system allowing the military more freedom to take drastic actions on short notice.

Comment: Yes ofc, but the way the doctor acts, it’s very obvious that it was already planned in the event of an outbreak. I think it should be safe to classify it as a plot hole